# Route traffic between Multiple webservers on dedicated server

Tags: webserver, vps, proxmox

I have a dedicated server with proxmox installed.
I have on it multiple vps and on each vps there is a website which is eather a domain or subdomain.
All have same Ip address.

How can i route traffic between all vps instances

> let say my domain is vps.com so
> 1.vps.com goes to vps 1

> 2.vps.com goes to vps 2

Do i need to create a vps that routes the traffic? I need the best method used in such situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is generic, in simple answer is Loadbalancer or reserve-proxy or rewrite. so I will cover more topics:

- You may need to use SSL which could cover CA ssl *.vps.com domain, (please note many provider provide free option like cloudflare) so that all subhosts are covered under umberlla regardless how many host are added. This simplifies SSL Part. Using let’s encrypt SSL for each subdomain (1.vps.com), (2.vps.com) will cause difficulties for you when you will scale in future. SO this is first and important point before you deploy loadbalancer.
- Depending on your environment/scale of traffic/platforms, loadbalancer are hardware based for on-premise or cloud based virtual instance. Depending on your requirement you can google it. Usually all does same job what your requirement is.
- If you are new in Loadbalancer part, I would suggest to use any opensource loadbalancer (google search) to test and try before purchasing any premium.
- If you are managing business critical related, then switch to AWS. https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/ or Cloudflare Loadbalancer to keep it simple.
- You can create many filteration rules or listen policy, CSP and webfilter in loadbalance to proxy or avoid bots or DDOS attacks. So This will improve your End-user’s interaction faster.
- Please note loadbalancer does have cache compatibility, so if your web app is having some sort of logged and guest session or if you are tracking login session via cookies on your real server, makes sure to check documentation and add by-pass cache policy for such query.
- Before implementing loadbalancer, make sure to adjust/adapt recommended setting for internal server like dns, apache/nginix config or HTTP ports related query. Again review the documentation. This will save you time.

Again your query was very general, I hope i was able to answer it in simple words.